# R plotly - overlapping points and labels

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny, plotly, ggrepel

I have an R shiny application and on one page I have a scatter plot with about 100 markers.
My goal is to add a label to each marker as explained here https://plotly.com/r/text-and-annotations/
It kind of words but the problem is that the text of each marker overlaps most of the time with text of other markers.
After some research, I learned there are packages like ggrepel https://ggrepel.slowkow.com/articles/examples.html that help fix this problem.
However, if I try to eventually reconvert the ggplot to plotly the text labels disappear.
I will show you an example:

```
df <- data.frame(xvals = rnorm(1:100), yvals = rnorm(1:100), label_var = paste0("label_",  as.character(round(rnorm(1:100),3))))
p <- ggplot(df, aes(xvals, yvals, label = label_var)) +  geom_point(color = "red")
p2 <- p + geom_text_repel() + labs(title = "geom_text_repel()") # visualize this plot. it's perfect
p3 <- plotly_build(p2) # visualize now p3, you see the labels have disappeared
```

what can I do to visualize in my shiny app a plot as displayed in p2?
Thanks

Comment: I'm afraid `plotly` does not support `geom_text_repel`. You should get a warning about that.

Comment: @stefan is right! Indeed running your code shows that the ggrepel is not yet implemented in plotly

Comment: @stefan Ok but does that mean there's no available solution for plotly? It's ok if I have to use different code and packages, I would just need a way to avoid overlapping. Thoughts?

Comment: Hi Angelo. Unfortunately no. ): I don't know of any other package like `ggrepel`. And even if there is any I would guess that you would run into the same issue.

Comment: Understood, many thanks Stefan for looking into this